# How does Twitter extract meaningful subject colors from image pixel data?

Tags: css, image, twitter, colors

Let me first clarify the problem statement. Check out this tweet:

https://twitter.com/jungledragon/status/926894337761345538

Next, click the image itself within the tweet. In the light box that appears, the menu bar below it takes on a meaningful color that is based on the actual pixels in the image itself. Even in this stress test, this is a difficult image given all the light pixels, does it do a fine job in picking an overall color that 1) represents the content of the image 2) is dark/contrasty enough to place white text on it:

[image]

I was simultaneously implementing a similar system before I even knew Twitter had this. Check out a preview below:

[image]

The examples in the screenshot are optimistic, as there are plenty of situations where the background is too light. Even in seemingly positive examples as seen in my screenshot, most of the time it does not pass the AA or AAA contrast check.

My current approach:

- One-time per image, a JS runs that calculates the average color of
  all pixels in the image. Note that the average color is not
  necessarily a meaningful color, such as in the edge case of the
  spider where the average would be close to white.
- I store the RGB value in the database
- Upon rendering the page (server-side) I dynamically set the
  background color of the image's caption using a formula

My formula is to convert the RGB to HSL, and then to manipulate in particular the S and L values. Given them a notch, using min/max values to set a treshold. I've tried countless combinations.

Yet it seems like a never-ending struggle because color darkness and contrast are subject to human perception.

Hence my curiosity on how Twitter seems to have nailed this, in particular two aspects:

1. Finding a meaningful subject color (not the same as average or dominant color)
2. Toning that meaningful color in a way that it remains recognizable (hue) yet is contrasty enough to place light text on it, whilst passing at least the AA contrast check.

I've searched around, but cannot find any information on their implementation. Anybody aware of they do it? Or other proven methods to solve this puzzle end-to-end?

Comment: My goodness, change that first image. Spiders shouldn't be allowed in a resolution higher than 20x20 px. With all the lovely animals you have in the miniatures you choose that one?

Comment: @PaoloForgia I'm afraid I'm the wrong person to tell, being a macro photographer that loves spiders :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a peek at Twitter's markup to see what I could find, and, after running a bit of code in the browser's console, it seems like Twitter takes a color average over a flat distribution of pixels in the images and scales each of the RGB channels to values of 64 and below. This provides a pretty fast way to create a high-contrast background for light text while still retaining a reasonable color match. From what I can tell, Twitter doesn't perform any advanced subject-color-detection, but I can't say for sure.

Here's a quick-and-dirty demo I made to validate this theory. The top and left borders that appear around the images initially display the color Twitter uses. After running the snippet, a bottom and right border appears with the calculated color. Requires 9+ for IE users.

```js
function processImage(img)
{
    var imageCanvas = new ImageCanvas(img);
    var tally = new PixelTally();

    for (var y = 0; y < imageCanvas.height; y += config.interval) {
        for (var x = 0; x < imageCanvas.width; x += config.interval) {
            tally.record(imageCanvas.getPixelColor(x, y));
        }
    }

    var average = new ColorAverage(tally);

    img.style.borderRightColor = average.toRGBStyleString();
    img.style.borderBottomColor = average.toRGBStyleString();
}

function ImageCanvas(img)
{
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    this.context2d = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.width = canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    this.height = canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;

    this.context2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    this.getPixelColor = function (x, y) {
        var pixel = this.context2d.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;

        return { red: pixel[0], green: pixel[1], blue: pixel[2] };
    }
}

function PixelTally()
{
    this.totalPixelCount = 0;
    this.colorPixelCount = 0;
    this.red = 0;
    this.green = 0;
    this.blue = 0;
    this.luminosity = 0;

    this.record = function (colors) {
        this.luminosity += this.calculateLuminosity(colors);
        this.totalPixelCount++;

        if (this.isGreyscale(colors)) {
            return;
        }

        this.red += colors.red;
        this.green += colors.green;
        this.blue += colors.blue;

        this.colorPixelCount++;
    };

    this.getAverage = function (colorName) {
        return this[colorName] / this.colorPixelCount;
    };

    this.getLuminosityAverage = function () {
        return this.luminosity / this.totalPixelCount;
    }

    this.getNormalizingDenominator = function () {
        return Math.max(this.red, this.green, this.blue) / this.colorPixelCount;
    };

    this.calculateLuminosity = function (colors) {
        return (colors.red + colors.green + colors.blue) / 3;
    };

    this.isGreyscale = function (colors) {
        return Math.abs(colors.red - colors.green) < config.greyscaleDistance
            && Math.abs(colors.red - colors.blue) < config.greyscaleDistance;
    };
}

function ColorAverage(tally)
{
    var lightness = config.lightness;
    var normal = tally.getNormalizingDenominator();
    var luminosityAverage = tally.getLuminosityAverage();

    // We won't scale the channels up to 64 for darker images:
    if (luminosityAverage < lightness) {
        lightness = luminosityAverage;
    }

    this.red = (tally.getAverage('red') / normal) * lightness
    this.green = (tally.getAverage('green') / normal) * lightness
    this.blue = (tally.getAverage('blue') / normal) * lightness

    this.toRGBStyleString = function () {
        return 'rgb('
            + Math.round(this.red) + ','
            + Math.round(this.green) + ','
            + Math.round(this.blue) + ')';
    };
}

function Configuration()
{
    this.lightness = 64;
    this.interval = 100;
    this.greyscaleDistance = 15;
}

var config = new Configuration();
var indicator = document.getElementById('indicator');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        config.lightness = Number(this.elements['lightness'].value);
        config.interval = Number(this.elements['interval'].value);
        config.greyscaleDistance = Number(this.elements['greyscale'].value);

        indicator.style.visibility = 'visible';

        setTimeout(function () {
            processImage(document.getElementById('image1'));
            processImage(document.getElementById('image2'));
            processImage(document.getElementById('image3'));
            processImage(document.getElementById('image4'));
            processImage(document.getElementById('image5'));

            indicator.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }, 50);
    });
});
```

```css
label { display: block; }
img { border-width: 20px; border-style: solid; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
#image1 { border-color: rgb(64, 54, 47) white white rgb(64, 54, 47); }
#image2 { border-color: rgb(46, 64, 17) white white rgb(46, 64, 17); }
#image3 { border-color: rgb(64, 59, 46) white white rgb(64, 59, 46); }
#image4 { border-color: rgb(36, 38, 20) white white rgb(36, 38, 20); }
#image5 { border-color: rgb(45, 53, 64) white white rgb(45, 53, 64); }
#indicator { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<form id="configuration_form">
    <p>
        <label>Lightness:
            <input name="lightness" type="number" min="1" max="255" value="64">
        </label>
        <label>Pixel Sample Interval:
            <input name="interval" type="number" min="1" max="255" value="100">
            (Lower values are slower)
        </label>
        <label>Greyscale Distance:
            <input name="greyscale" type="number" min="1" max="255" value="15">
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Run</button> (Wait for images to load first!)
    </p>
    <p id="indicator">Running...this may take a few moments.</p>
</form>

<p>
    <img id="image1" crossorigin="Anonymous" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DNz9fNqWAAAtoGu.jpg:large">
    <img id="image2" crossorigin="Anonymous" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DOdX8AGXUAAYYmq.jpg:large">
    <img id="image3" crossorigin="Anonymous" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DOYp0HQX4AEWcnI.jpg:large">
    <img id="image4" crossorigin="Anonymous" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DOQm1NzXkAEwxG7.jpg:large">
    <img id="image5" crossorigin="Anonymous" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DN6gVnpXUAIxlxw.jpg:large">
</p>
```

The code ignores white, black, and grey-ish pixels when determining the dominant color from the image which gives us a more vivid saturation despite reducing the brightness of the color. The computed color is pretty close to the original color from Twitter for most of the images.

We can improve this experiment by changing which parts of the image we calculate the average color from. The example above selects pixels uniformly across the whole image, but we can try using only pixels near the edges of the image—so the color blends more seamlessly—or we can try averaging color values from the center of the image to highlight the subject. I'll expand on the code and update this answer later when I have some more time.

Comment: Thank you for a very high quality answer! You're giving me lots of food for thought and things to try. I still need to take some time to fully grasp all details. In particular, can you give some more guidance on what you mean with "scaling RGB channels to 64 or below"? What does that mean specifically? I'll award the bountry but SO says I need to wait 1 hour.

Comment: @Ferdy YW! It was an interesting question. By scaling the channels, I mean that Twitter takes the RGB values in a 0-255 range and reduces the values proportionately so that they all fall between 0 and 64, which are relatively dark colors (good backgrounds). So if a channel contained the value 255, it scales down to 64, 100 scales to 25, etc. The code above also scales particularly dark colors back up to 64 as Twitter seems to do. Let me know if you have questions...I'll try to add comments to the code later. And go ahead and leave the bounty up...I'm curious to see what others come up with :)

Comment: Get it now, thanks! I won't be until friday until I have enough time to play with the scaling, but it looks very promising. I've already awarded the bounty now, well deserved! Perhaps as an extra bonus challenge, it would be nice if the scaling leads to a guaranteed contrast score that complies with AA and/or AAA, but that's pushing it.

Comment: @Ferdy - given that this approach limits the three RGB channels to a maximum value of 64/255, we can achieve AAA contrast ratio using text as dark as 213/255 (about 83.5% of full white). That sounds pretty close to a guarantee to me!

Comment: How can such a great quality answer have so few reps? Nice it got a bounty, cool stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the example below might be found helpful for what you want to accomplish.

```js
function getAverageColourAsRGB(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rgb = {
      r: 102,
      g: 102,
      b: 102
    },
    pixelInterval = 5,
    count = 0,
    i = -4,
    data, length;
  if (!context) {
    return rgb;
  }
  var height = canvas.height = img.naturalHeight || img.offsetHeight || img.height,
    width = canvas.width = img.naturalWidth || img.offsetWidth || img.width;
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  try {
    data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return rgb;
  }
  data = data.data;
  length = data.length;
  while ((i += pixelInterval * 4) < length) {
    count++;
    rgb.r += data[i];
    rgb.g += data[i + 1];
    rgb.b += data[i + 2];
  }
  rgb.r = Math.floor(rgb.r / count);
  rgb.g = Math.floor(rgb.g / count);
  rgb.b = Math.floor(rgb.b / count);
  return rgb;
}

function getContrastYIQ(r, g, b) {
  var yiq = ((r * 299) + (g * 587) + (b * 114)) / 1000;
  return (yiq >= 128) ? '#000' : '#FFF';
}

function rgb2hex(rgb) {
  rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?/i);
  return (rgb && rgb.length === 4) ? "#" +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) : '';
}

function convertHex(hex) {
  hex = hex.replace('#', '');
  if (hex.length === 3) {
    hex = hex + hex;
  }
  r = parseInt(hex.substring(0, 2), 16);
  g = parseInt(hex.substring(2, 4), 16);
  b = parseInt(hex.substring(4, 6), 16);
  return [r, g, b];
}

function colorSubH(colorA, colorB) {
  rgbA = convertHex(colorA);
  rgbB = convertHex(colorB);
  c = [];
  for (i = 0; i < rgbA.length; i++) {
    c.push(parseInt((rgbA[i] + rgbB[i]) / 2));
  }
  return rgb2hex("rgb(" + c.join(",") + ")");
}
var myImg = document.getElementById("img1");
var color = getAverageColourAsRGB(myImg);
var colorArray = [color.r, color.g, color.b];
var bgColor = rgb2hex("rgb(" + colorArray.join(","));
var txtColor = getContrastYIQ(color.r, color.g, color.b)
var subHColor = colorSubH(txtColor, bgColor);
var footer = document.getElementsByClassName("imgFooter")[0];
footer.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
footer.style.color = txtColor;
var span = footer.querySelector("span");
span.style.color = subHColor;
```

```css
.main {
  width: 25rem;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.main .imgFooter {
  position: relative;
  height: 2rem;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  width: 23rem;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img id="img1" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
  />
  <div class="imgFooter">
    Header
    <br>
    <span>
Sub-header
</span>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ty, but I'm getting an error when running the code.

Comment: @Ferdy which part is faulty? The snippet runs fine with the example image. Can you post the error message?

Comment: It was saying something about a negative value, but it does work now. Can you perhaps explain the logic of the example?

Comment: @Ferdy you are right it needs further explaining i will add proper comments later on.